# refomulate statement with modulo

Tags: if-statement, math, logic, addition, modulo

I have following statement:

```
b != (j % 3 + a ) % 2
```

How can I reformulate this statement that `a` is alone one side like

```
a != .....
```

with this restriction?
 `0 <= a,b <= 2`

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no way to do what you're asking.  You can't "invert" a modulo operator.  If you could, modern encryption would all collapse.  Remember for EVERY value of `a` and `j`, `b` is either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

If j%3 = 0 and b=0 then a cannot be even. This requires two inequalities, a!=0 and a!=2; one won't do. So there is no more general single inequality, because that would produce a single inequality when specialized to j%3 = 0 and b=0, which can't work.